# Browse ADAM and retrieve values from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, adam

This is my current PowerShell code:

`connect-QADService -service 'view.domain.com' -Credential 'MyDomain\Administrator'`

`$AllVMs= ( get-QADObject -SearchRoot 'vdi.vmware.int/Servers' -type pae-VM -IncludedProperties ipHostNumber,pae-SIDString )`

How it can be rewrited in C# (.net 3.5) ?

Comment: Do you mean how can you invoke this powershell script via c#, or do you mean how can you completely replace this script with c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://view.domain.com/OU=Servers,DC=vdi,DC=vmware,DC=int", "domain\\Administrator", "paSSw0rd");

DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
ds.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(new String[] { "pae-SIDString", "ipHostNumber" });
```

Works like a charm :)